# To what extent is Postgres able to reuse indices?

Tags: postgresql

For example if I build an index on

A, B, C

And then subsequently build an index on

A, B, D

Is the original A, B portion reused or is everything built again from scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, each index is a new individual object. Check [pg_class](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-class.html).

Edit: You don't have to create two indexes holding the A and B columns twice. Create an index on A, B and C and then another index on D. PostgreSQL can use two indexes, when needed.

Comment: If you use one of C or D much more often than the other, you might even index on (A,B,C) and (D) too (reverse is D is the more popular one).  The 3-column index can be used to satisfy (A,B) queries, then combined with the one on (D).  You only want to do this if the (A,B,C) combination is really common though, because the 3-column index is going to be larger than the 2-column one.

Answer (score 1):

It's a new index each time as noted by Frank.

Also note that frequently, a single-column index is actually enough unless you're constantly ordering by C with a relevant `where` constraint on A and B along with a limit clause. When not, Postgres's planner will be smart enough to use a [bitmap index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap_index), as discussed in the documentation notes on [multi-column indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-multicolumn.html).

Comment: The linked page mentions "Multicolumn indexes should be used sparingly. In most situations, an index on a single column is sufficient and saves space and time. Indexes with more than three columns are unlikely to be helpful unless the usage of the table is extremely stylized." [Combining Multiple Indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-bitmap-scans.html) gives more details on actual combination considerations.